# PHP and JSON. How to get a specific element? //Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, json

My JSON file

```
{

  "shopId": 29,

  "last": 46977914,

  "freshfood": [

  {

     "freshfood_id": 2629,

     "food": [

        {

           "food_id": 1740851,

           "type": "fruit",

           "status": 1

        },

        {

           "food_id": 1730905,

           "type": "vegetable",

           "status": 1

           },
        ]
     }
  ]
}
```

I need to get second food_id (1730905)

I try this, but it does not work.

```
$string = file_get_contents("food.json");
$json_a=json_decode($string,true);
echo $GetFreshFoodId = $json_a['freshfood'][1]['freshfood_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

`$json_a['freshfood']['food'][1]['food_id'];`

Answer (score 0):

It´s a syntrax error in your json file.
Your last entry in "food": [ ... ] has a comma. 
That´s the reason why you get NULL when you´re run json_decode

```
{

  "shopId": 29,

  "last": 46977914,

  "freshfood": [

  {

     "freshfood_id": 2629,

     "food": [

        {

           "food_id": 1740851,

           "type": "fruit",

           "status": 1

        },

        {

           "food_id": 1730905,

           "type": "vegetable",

           "status": 1

           },
        ]
     }
  ]
}
```